# Objective C: Detecting Leakages via Instruments in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, instruments

I ran the instruments on my app and found some leaks, however I am not sure how I can decipher the results for example I clicked on the line '_NSArrayM'

[image]

After which I clicked on one of the entries in the details column and the following was displayed,

[image]

What does '100%' mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 100% means all the leaks Instruments detected in that function were in the highlighted line of code. If your function was leaking memory in multiple places, the individual percentages would be lower, but they would add up to 100%.

Comment: Well, it means that the leaked objects Instruments detected were *allocated* in the highlighted line of code. Not necessarily that the incorrect memory management was there.