# Info button and percentage meaning in Instruments->Leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, instruments

What is the meaning of this percentage that's shown next to the highlighted line in Instruments? (This window opens in the Call Tree -> Leaked Blocks of Instruments, when you double click on a symbol name)

Thx![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the following question to learn what the percentage next to a line of code means:

[Objective C: Detecting Leakages via Instruments in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561932/objective-c-detecting-leakages-via-instruments-in-xcode/6564444#6564444)

Answer (score 0):

The percentage just shows the chance of the leak in the particular line

Comment: But what is it that leaks there? Aren't all the methods return autoreleased objects in the blue-highlighted lines there? That's why I'm confused with the percentage thing and all...